# How can i calculate the modes of an array and ignore a data

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to calculate the `mode` of an array which I can do, but I want to exclude the 0

This is my code :

const datas = [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 0];

```
function mode(numbers) {
  var modes = [],
    count = [],
    i,
    number,
    maxIndex = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
    number = numbers[i];
    count[number] = (count[number] || 0) + 1;
    if (count[number] > maxIndex) {
      maxIndex = count[number];
    }
  }

  for (i in count)
    if (count.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      if (count[i] === maxIndex) {
        modes.push(Number(i));
      }
    }

  return modes;
}

mode(datas); // output : [0] and I want [4] [2]
```

Thanks for you time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) out zeroes:

```js
datas = [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 0];

function mode(numbers) {
  // we don't want to consider zeros
  // so filter them out
  numbers = numbers.filter(function(n) { return n !== 0 }); 

  var modes = [],
    count = [],
    i, number, maxIndex = 0;

  for (i = 0; i < numbers.length; i += 1) {
    number = numbers[i];
    count[number] = (count[number] || 0) + 1;
    if (count[number] > maxIndex) {
      maxIndex = count[number];
    }
  }

  for (i in count)
    if (count.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
      if (count[i] === maxIndex) {
        modes.push(Number(i));
      }
    }

  return modes;
}

console.log(mode(datas)) // output : [4] [2]
```

If you're using ES6, you can use the arrow function syntax:

```
numbers = numbers.filter(n => n !== 0);
```

Comment: Even easier, `.filter(n => n)` will filter them out :)

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share a way to calculate the `mode` without `for`/`forEach` loops.

Relevant docs:

- [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)
- [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys)
- [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values)
- [spread syntax (...)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)
- [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)
- [Math.max](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/max)

```js
const counted = [0, 0, 0, 4, 4, 2, 3, 2, 0]
.filter(element => element)
.reduce(
  (accumulator, currentValue) => 
    ({
      ...accumulator,
      [currentValue]: (accumulator[currentValue] || 0) + 1
    }),
  {}
);

const maxCount = Math.max(...Object.values(counted));

const mode = Object.keys(counted).filter(key => counted[key] === maxCount);

console.log(mode);
```